# Cloud datastore as a mongodb replacement

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking to use a fully managed mongodb substitution (outside of [Cloud Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/pricing)).

What would be the closest equivalent? My first thought was Google's [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/), but I've never used that. How close is that to mongo? And are their others that are perhaps even closer that could be used on GCP, Azure, or AWS?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles upon this question in 2021, Azure Cosmos DB has MongoDB API now. It is a drop-in replacement as it works with existing MongoDB clients. Just change the connection string and you are good to go. No change in your software needed. I think this is the closest you can get right now beside the Cloud Atlas option.

Documentation for it is right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction

Beware: This is still Cosmos DB under the hood. There is no running MongoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

From the [options you have inside Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/), Datastore would be the first option closest to MongoBD since it’s a NoSQL document database; unless you want to develop for mobile (then you need Firestore for Firebase) or if you need to work with something more powerful than Datastore you have BigTable.

Once you have the data in Cloud Datastore you will be able to access natively from [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/creating-entities) but also from [App Engine flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-datastore) or a Kubernetes cluster using the [Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/) and the [client libraries in several languages](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries).

Answer (score -1):

You could always use Amazon DynamoDB (https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)
According to the Docs,

> Amazon DynamoDB is a key-value and document database that delivers single-digit millisecond performance at any scale. It's a fully managed, multiregion, multimaster database with built-in security, backup and restore, and in-memory caching for internet-scale applications. DynamoDB can handle more than 10 trillion requests per day and support peaks of more than 20 million requests per second.

It is a tested and tried solution and works pretty well

Comment: thanks, how does DynamoDB compare to MongoDB then? Are they interchangeable, or entirely different in how they approach/store data?

Comment: Check https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-dynamodb for the comparison from official MongoDB docs

Comment: DynamoDB has less features compared to mongodb, but it's truly scalable(up to 80000 reads and 80000 writes per second, total limit per account per region). You have 2 pricing models: on-demand pay as you use or provisioned (pay regardless you use it or not). You can have triggers to call other aws services, like the mongo events and you can replicate to across regions.